# Where do these common expressions for polarization and magnetization come from?

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm referring to these:

$$\vec{P}=\epsilon_0(\epsilon_r-1)\vec{E} \ ; \ \vec{M}=(\mu_r-1)\vec{H} $$

I have seen them in many of my lecture notes and books, but I haven't found an answer as to why they are in this form.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here. Why is $\vec{P}$ proportional to $\vec{E}$? Why is the constant of proportionality defined in this way? Etc. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the *definitions* of the quantities $\epsilon_r$ and $\mu_r$, and apply when the polarization $\bf P$  and magnetization $\bf M$ are linear functions of the applied fields.

The definitions are more usualy written as
$$
{\bf D}= \epsilon_0 {\bf E}+{\bf P}= \epsilon_0 \epsilon_r {\bf E}\\
{\bf H}= \frac 1{\mu_0}{\bf B}+{\bf M}= \frac{1}{\mu_0\mu_r} {\bf B}.
$$
and ${\bf J}_{\rm bound}= \partial_t {\bf P}+ {\rm curl\,} {\bf M}$, while $\rho_{\rm bound}= {\rm div\,} {\bf P}$ are compatible with
$$
{\rm curl\,} {\bf H} = {\bf J}_{\rm free}+ \partial_t {\bf D}\\
{\rm div\,}{\bf D}= \rho_{\rm free},\\
\partial_t \rho_{\rm bound}+ {\rm div\,} {\bf J}_{\rm bound}  
$$

Comment: Oh, okay, that makes more sense! Thank you.